# Reference converter in another xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-10-mobile, staticresource, windows-10-universal

I got a datatemplate in `Resource.xaml`:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SplitViewMenuItemWithCount">
    <RelativePanel>
        <RelativePanel RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" Margin="0,10,0,10">
            <SymbolIcon Foreground="White" Width="25" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" Symbol="{Binding Symbol}" x:Name="SymbolIcon" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Count, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, TargetNullValue=Collapsed, FallbackValue=Collapsed}" x:Name="StackPanelCount" RelativePanel.RightOf="SymbolIcon" Margin="0,20,0,0" CornerRadius="9" Background="White" Width="15" Height="15">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count, FallbackValue='0'}" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Foreground="{StaticResource AppDarkBlueColor}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="White" x:Name="TextBlockMenuItemText" RelativePanel.RightOf="StackPanelCount" Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="16" Padding="5,3,0,5"/>
        </RelativePanel>
    </RelativePanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I'm using the datatemplate in my MainPage.xaml as a datatemplate for a ListView, but it crashes because my `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`. It can't find the converter in `Resource.xaml`.

However if I put the datatemplate in my `MainPage.Resources` it finds the converter (because it's defined there).

Is there any way to keep the datatemplate in `Resource.xaml`? I rather have it there than in `MainPage.Resources`.

Comment: add this to your ResourceDictionary: <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter  x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />

Comment: May you post your whole code ?

Comment: @Dani weird that didn't work at first when I tried, got some xaml-error. But it works now for some reason. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a reference from your mainPage.xaml to your resources.xaml by using **ResourceDictionnary** tag as following:

```
<Window x:Class="MainPage"  ...  ... >
     <Window.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourProjectDLL;component/Resource.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         </ResourceDictionary>
     </Window.Resources>
     <Grid>
          ... Your window body
     </Grid>
</Window>
```